# How to clean grain bags?

Tags: cleaning, grain, partial-mash

I did a partial mash tonight, and I want to reuse my grain bag for future uses. I tried to rinse it out, but pieces of grain are still in there. What do you guys do to clean it out fully? Throw it in the wash?

Comment: What type of bag are you using, nylon?

Comment: Sorry, yes nylon mesh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My process usually looks like this:

- Empty as much of the bag out into the trash as I can
- Rinse the bag under running water, getting off whatever bits I can from the outside
- Turn the bag inside-out
- Continue to rinse under running water, while mashing and rubbing the bag together in my hands

I find that the last step does a pretty good job, and the rubbing makes it go so much faster than just trying to "push" the bits of grain off with the sprayer.

Answer (score 3):

I neeeeever quite get all the little bits unstuck.  Fortunately brewing is rather forgiving.  Any little bits that still make it will just end up going along for the ride in the next batch.  The wort is still being boiled, so any baddies hanging out in the few specks of grain aren't going to make it through.  Dunk it in star-san just beforehand if you want to feel extra warm and fuzzy.  The little bits of husk left aren't going to leech any noticable amount of tannin or anything.  Just make sure you clean everything you can readily get, and RDWHAHB about the rest.

Answer (score 2):

After my first partial mash I just let my nylon bag sit in a bowl of hot water for about 15 minutes and then just rinsed the bag really well with the sprayer attachment on my faucet.  All the color and bits of grain came right out.  I think it also helped that I turned the bag inside out to clean it as most of what was stuck to the bag was on the inside.